# Text Size of a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

How can I decrease the font size of my spinner?  I have reduced the spinner size to 35 pix because of which my text gets cut in half.

How do i do that? Also I dont want anything to be selected beforehand.

Default text should be `"select some value"`.

Comment: I don't know a lot about spinner but if I remember well, it uses an ArrayAdapter to display the elements. I then suppose that you could subclass it, and override getView ? It's just an idea, I haven't tested it. I'll have a go at it.

Answer (score 22):

after some tests, there is an easier way than subclassing ArrayAdapter. Change the

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);//this is from the tutorial, adapt with your line
```

to this line :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.textview);
```

You just have to change the design of the TextView you use of the Spinner. I just tried with this, as the layout of the textview.xml :

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="30sp"></TextView>
```

Answer (score 10):

Changing

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

to  `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.textview);`

will change only the item which is visible by default on the spinner. If we need the same style to be applied on all the items in the spinner, we need to change

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)   to 


adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview);
```

Answer (score 4):

define 2 xml: R.layout.spinner_item, R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textSize="18sp" >
</TextView>
```

spinner_dropdown_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

--------------------------------Update--------------------------------------

The rest code:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
RelativeLayout relative = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
spinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

relative.addView(spinner);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setCustomView(relative);

// Set adapter and listener
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Comment: Once these 2 XML files are defined, how are they incorporated into the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `android:scaleX` and `anrdoid:scaleY` seems like an easy way to change the spinner font size.