# how to reduce spinner font size in code?

Tags: android

Actually I need to reduce the font size of spinner via code, below is my code:

```
  Spinner spiner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner2); 
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("list 1"); 
  list.add("list 2");
  list.add("list 3"); 
  ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.trytry,list); 
  dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
  spiner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I created an xml file named as trytry.xml to mention in ArrayAdapter but in SetContentView I mentioned setContentView(R.layout.main); I'm confused how to do it

my trytry xml contains:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:text="@+id/TextView01"    
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="18dp"> 
</TextView> 
 </Spinner>
```

Comment: `ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.YOURLAYOUT,list);`

Comment: R.layout.YOURLAYOUT wat tat mean,, is ther any problem if setContentView(R.layout.main); but my layout xml file was trytry.xml

Comment: Main is the layout for the whole screen, the other is the layout for the spinner contained in the main screen.

Comment: Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329310/text-size-of-a-spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `sp` for test size `android:textSize="18sp"`

Use this code

```
public class AndroidCustomSpinner extends Activity {

   String[] DayOfWeek = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday",
               "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                           R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, DayOfWeek);
      mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/weekofday"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="18sp
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tried 18sp now ,, im getting force close error. if i debug it runs whole code (upto last line),, in logcat it showing lot of errors.how to find the exact error?

Comment: 07-07 18:12:25.002: E/AndroidRuntime(2182): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182):  at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:461)
07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:622)

Comment: 07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
07-07 18:12:25.160: E/AndroidRuntime(2182):  at android.widget.AbsSpinner.onMeasure(AbsSpinner.java:198)

Answer (score 0):

Several issues going on.

First, when you create your own layout, it should not be prefixed by `android`.  That is reserved for layouts that come with the framework.  For your own layout it should be `R.id.trytry`.

Second, you need to set your layout to both the closed state (in the initial call to the adapter) and as the dropdown resource if you want it to look the same when it opens.

It should look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);              //  Set the layout for the whole screen
                // Other code here
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.trytry,list);   
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.trytry); 
}
```

Also, you cannot add a view inside a spinner definition.  This is giving you errors.

The spinner tag should be in your main.xml like this:

```
<Spinner 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then your trytry.xml should look like this:

```
<TextView    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:text="@+id/TextView01"       
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"      
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:textSize="18dp"/>
```